# Not added .col-xs-12 to bootstrap coloumb , hiding it , WHY ?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

hey guys i was just playng around with bootstraps col-md-*'s and came up with the following complex example , have a look :

HTML :

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin. He lay on his armour-like back, and if he lifted his head a little he could see his brown belly, slightly domed and divided by arches into stiff sections. The bedding was hardly able to cover it and seemed ready to slide off any moment. His many legs, pitifully thin compared with the size of the rest of him, waved about helplessly as he looked. "What's happened to me? " he thought.
                </div>
                <div class=" col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos commodi aliquam nostrum eius vel rem perferendis, qui sequi pariatur voluptas officia reprehenderit distinctio placeat. Minima nihil culpa atque suscipit deserunt.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

there is a small problem , at widths of 980 and below , only the secound `.col-md-12` is visible , and i am not able to figure out why this is happening ?

**[FIDDLE HERE.](http://jsfiddle.net/pjv5wdam/)**

now this problem can be solved by adding a `col-xs-12` to the 2nd `col-md-6` as follows

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin. He lay on his armour-like back, and if he lifted his head a little he could see his brown belly, slightly domed and divided by arches into stiff sections. The bedding was hardly able to cover it and seemed ready to slide off any moment. His many legs, pitifully thin compared with the size of the rest of him, waved about helplessly as he looked. "What's happened to me? " he thought.
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos commodi aliquam nostrum eius vel rem perferendis, qui sequi pariatur voluptas officia reprehenderit distinctio placeat. Minima nihil culpa atque suscipit deserunt.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

But i am really really curious to know what causes the initaial problem that i showed.

can somebody explain ?

Thank you.

Alex-z.

Comment: It seems that your css being this `div[class^="col-md-6"] {
    height: 100px;
}` is covering the text of the top div. change the height as I did here to 100px and you can start to see the text.

Answer (score 1):

You can see in the screenshot below with the div set to 100px
`div[class^="col-md-6"] {height: 100px;}` how it covers part of the text below.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

Dear this is bootstrap grid system behavior

the class `.col-lg-` only visible when device width (≥1200px)
the class `.col-md-` only visible when device width (≥992px)
the class `.col-sm-` only visible when device width (≥768px)
the class `.col-xs-` visible all time.

see the link below
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Comment: i totally understand that , i am  trying to understand the behaviour i notice in the question i have posted !

Comment: The behavior is in the media queries
@media (min-width:1200px) {
    .col-lg-
}

Answer (score -1):

The behavior is in the media queries

```
@media (min-width:1200px) {
    .col-lg-
}
```

so that this class is not visible when device is less than 1200px 
if you put a class `.col-lg-*` in a width less than 1200px; it is not found in the css file so it will be displayed block and will not be affected by any float 
 it will act as `float:none` instead of `float:left` 
and so on ..............

Comment: i don't think you understood the question !